# Error coming while using Random Forest using R

Tags: r

I am using a dataset containing `mvar_1` as column, having names of one of 5 parties that citizen voted for last year. Other variables are just demographic variables, as the number of rallies attended for each parties, other stuffs.

When I use the following code:

```
data.model.rf = randomForest(mvar_1 ~ mvar_2 + mvar_3 + mvar_4 + mvar_5 + 
                             mvar_6 + mvar_7 + mvar_8 + mvar_9 + mvar_10 + 
                             mvar_11 + mvar_15 + mvar_17 + mvar_18 + mvar_21 + 
                             mvar_22 + mvar_23 + mvar_24 + mvar_25 + mvar_26 +
                             mvar_28, data=data.train, ntree=20000, mtry=15, 
                             importance=TRUE, na.action = na.omit )
```

This error message appears:

```
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 53 categories.
```

Comment: One of your `mvar` is a factor with more than 53 levels. So either you have a categorical variable with lots of levels, like demographic group, and you should aggregate it into less level to use this package, OR, maybe more likely, you have a non-categorical variable incorrectly typed as a factor. In this case you should fix it.

Comment: no, i have before only defined mvar_1 as catagorical variable ..... which one of 5 party names.

Comment: other variables are just to be given importance based on R.F. analysis, i.e. how they help in predicting catagorical variable mvar_1

Comment: you _think_ you have only defined one categorical variable, but some of your other `mvar` may be typed incorrectly. It's worth checking, using `summary`. in any case we cannot help more without seeing your data. Consider adding the ouput of `dput(head(data.train))` to your post.

Answer (score 9):

One of your mvar is a factor with more than 53 levels.

You may have a categorical variable with lots of levels, like demographic group, and you should aggregate it into less levels to use this package. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510142/data-transformation-in-r-better-to-operate-on-row-values-or-factor-levels/32510665#32510665) for the best way of doing it)

More likely, you have a non-categorical variable incorrectly typed as a factor. In this case you should fix it by typing your variable correctly. E.g. to get a numeric from a factor, you call `as.numeric(as.character(myfactor))`.

If you don't know what a factor is, the second option is probably it. You should do a `summary` of `data.train`, this will help you see which `mvar` are incorrectly typed. If the `mvar` is typed as numeric, you will see min, max, mean, median, etc. If a numeric variable is incorrectly typed as a factor, you will not see that but you will see the number of occurence of each level.

In any case, calling `summary` will help you because it shows the number of levels for each factor. The variables with >53 levels are causing the issue.

Comment: Actually a more legible output is given by the function `str`. Try `str(df)`. You can identify the factor w/ lots of levels in no time.

Comment: Thanks! Casting the factors as numerics didn't work for me. But what worked was using ``strip.white = TRUE`` when importing the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but solved it after seeing that I had imported the data frame with comma separators without indicating it.

After importing the table using `read.table(data, dec=",")` the problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem - error message suggesting >53 factor levels, but none of my variables were like that.

Upon further inspection, I found I had some factor variables with empty levels.

I used the forcats function fct_drop to remove these, then everything worked!

Answer (score -1):

As antoine-sac pointed out, in my case this error was because of numeric variables appearing as factors. Only that the conversion happened by R when it was importing my (numeric) file.

Casting the factors as numerics didn't work. But what worked was using `strip.white = TRUE` when importing the dataset. (I found this solution [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/13589_1dc68b35cccc4686924ba80c37697b7e.html).)

Comment: I'm a little curious as to why this was downvoted. I spent more than half an hour looking for the solution, trying everything suggested in this thread and elsewhere, and was eventually relieved to find the solution to my problem.

Comment: It was likely downvoted because it looks like your issue was already answered by @asachet. Adding an additional post to concur with another answer doesn't really "add anything" to the original post. The better solution here would be to edit your original post, indicate what the problem was and the solution. You should also mark asachet's post as the best answer.

Answer (score -2):

This error occurs when you train your model with the entire dataset and not with the train data. Try implementing the model with train data and work out with test adm to perform prediction.

Comment: Although training on the entire dataset is indeed a bad practice, using a train set won't help here as the issue comes from the fact that a factor has more than 53 levels, this would also happen using a train set.