# using randomForest but saying can't handle more than 53 categories error

Tags: r

I am using the randomForest function but it says can't handle categorical predictions with more than 53 categories. I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

```
myrf <- randomForest(x = strain[,-9], 
                     y = strain[,9], 
                     mtry = 3, 
                     ntree = 400,
                     importance = T)
```

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce your issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: In the meantime, a simple google search turns up several posts about this on the Stack Exchange network, for example [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157331/random-forest-predictors-have-more-than-53-categories).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error coming while using Random Forest using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098731/error-coming-while-using-random-forest-using-r)