# Products Category classification in R

Tags: r, algorithm, classification, product

I have about 30000 records of unique products and their different categories (about 500). Every product is assigned to one of these categories and there are multiple products assigned to one category. Only 2 columns in the dataset: product name and product category. Now, how to build a machine learning model to classify these products in R. Can someone help me to move in right direction.

---

Comment: this type of classification comes under decision trees, check `randomforest` package

Comment: I have already used randomforest algorithm but it is giving below error as there more than 500 categories:                                                  
         Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : ,,,,,,,,,,
  Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 53 categories.,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: You may have a categorical variable with lots of levels and you should aggregate it into less levels to use this package. Chances are you have a non-categorical variable incorrectly typed as a factor. 
I suggest **1.** convert `factor` to `numeric` by `as.numeric(as.character(myFactor))` **2.** Find most occuring categories and reduce the levels as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32510665/6779509)

Comment: Refer this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwt6XEh7U3g&feature=youtu.be&t=44m32s) for another approach